# getting 500 internal server error for csrf token generation when url parameters has %40

Tags: javascript, java, url, csrf, csrf-token

For url if I want to create CSRF token it will give me 500 internal server error

```
https://abc/conf.tmpl?Email=ychandra-d%40dd.com&training=234
```

but if use @ instead of %40, csrf token will generate

```
https://abc/conf.tmpl?Email=ychandra-d@0dd.com&training=234
```

**Can someone help me with this why changing in url pattern creates error? DO I need to added any other dependencies for special character?**

Done some Implementation and add some file regarding csrf -

*File added -*

csrfguard.js

csrfguard.properties

*Done some implementation-*

In web.xml add csrfGuardServlet, Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config, Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config.Print, csrfGuardFilter(its filter-mapping), CsrfGuardServletContextListener,CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener

In apply.tmpl file added

```
<script src="https://weblibrary.cdn.getgo.com/web-library-2/scripts/web-library.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/csrfguard"></script>
```

as in web.xml file

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>csrfGuardServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/public/csrfguard</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the email parameter is URL-encoded properly. %40 is the URL-encoded representation of the '@' symbol. When constructing the URL, use proper URL encoding to represent special characters.

```
String encodedEmail = URLEncoder.encode("ychandra-d@dd.com", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
String url = "https://abc/conf.tmpl?Email=" + encodedEmail + "&training=234";
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL query component is encoded. You are not fully decoding it. %40 is the encoded form of @. Technically,  @ is not required to be encoded in the query component, but your server is doing so.

After you split the query data on & and =, you need to decode the resulting substrings by replacing the %XX hex sequences with the corresponding bytes, and then converting the resulting bytes to string characters based on whatever charset your server uses (usually utf-8, but not always).